# MATLAB matrix of variables operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I have AX = B, where A is a n x n matrix, and B = [b1(t); b2(t); b3(t); ... ; bn(t)]. So X would be a n x 1 matrix, with each entries as a function of t.

How would I be able to find X, using either gauss elimination, LU decomposition, or any other methods?

Comment: My matrix algebra is very stale but isn't `X` just `A\B` ? (i.e. inverse(A)*B)

Answer (score 1):

LU Decomposition is an inbuilt function available with Matlab. See [here.](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/lu.html)

Comment: I didn't know this would work for symbolic computations as well. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

LU-factorization:

```
[L, U, P] = lu(A);

X = (U \ (L \ (P * B)));
```

You could also simply do

```
X = A\B;
```

Which exploits any potential special structures of A, that could speed up the calculations.